# Book about an apprentice whose master reanimates a dead bird

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am not sure if the mentor was *exactly* magic. The only things I can remember are that the mentor/mentor was a pseudo adopted parent-child situation, though the old guy was a bit of a jerk.

The most major moment though that comes to me is that the grouchy old man is made to 'revive' a pet bird to get out of a sticky situation in the latter half of the book.

The old man also explains that he can't bring things back to life and that'll stop moving and drop back down dead.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art or any character or place names?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @DavidW It was about 11 years ago in a high-school library, along side the the Gracling duology at the time